# Use Lang.js in a component property

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I want to parse a Lang.js localized string as a property to a component.

```html
<my-component :placeholder="placeholder"></my-component>
```

```
export default {
        name: 'Test',
        data: function() {
            return {
                placeholder: {{ 'messages.Placeholder' | trans }}, <!-- not working -->
            }
        },
        methods: {
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately `placeholder: {{ 'messages.Placeholder' | trans }}` wont work

Comment: when u use: (| trans) it's a vue filter?

Comment: Yes it is. Vue.filter('trans', (...args) => {
    return Language.get(...args);
});

Comment: When u use : before any directive this mean than you are binding it then you can assign it some expression like :placeholder="'myText' | trans" this text will be modified depending his filter function. Also u can't use {{ }} inside you script because this interpolation is just for be use in template and there u can put inside some expression.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easier as expacted.

```html
<my-component :placeholder="'messages.Placeholder' | trans"></my-component>
```